# Blazor Wasm in subfolder

Tags: iis, blazor, subdirectory

I have two blazor wasm applications I would like to host withing the same root folder as follows:

**MainSite

     |_ Customers**

Each of those are seperate applications.
Is it possible to host the 'customers' wasm site within the same 'root' folder but treat it as completely seperate application? i.e.

http://localhost:8999/ (takes you to -> **Root Site**)

http://localhost:8999/Customers (takes you to -> **/Customers**)

I have tried to to the following without any luck:

a) modified `<base href="/" />` to `<base href="/customers/" />` for subfolder 'customers' application

b) added some url rewrite rules in 'customers/web.config'

```
<rewrite>
       <rules>
            <rule name="ExampleToDemo">
                <match url="^(.*)customers" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="^(.*)customers\wwwroot\{R:0}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="SPA fallback routing 2" stopProcessing="true"> 
                <match url="^(.*)customers" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                </conditions> 
                <action type="Rewrite" url="customers\wwroot\" /> 
            </rule> 
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Root site works as expected:
[image]

Sub directory 'Customers' shows this:
[image]

Instead of this:

[image]

How can I make the sub dir customers site work using the /customers path?

Comment: See my answers on the following links on multi SPA hosting.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66701682/is-it-possible-to-have-two-multiple-clients-hosted-on-the-same-server-in-a-bla and https://stackoverflow.com/a/66705921/13065781.

Comment: You can use failed request tracking to view detailed request information, or you can just tell me which url you want to redirect to which url, I will make demo for you.

Comment: Hello samwu, the MainSite should be directed to the http://localhost:8999/
whereas Customers should be directed to the http://localhost:8999/Customers url. They are both seperate Wasm applications.

Comment: What is the url to sub dir customers? Do you want to redirect from sub dir customers to `http://localhost:8999/Customers`?

Comment: samwu correct i would like to direct them to sub dir customers i.e. http://localhost:8999/Customers
I have tried following @MrCakaShaunCurtis solution but it is not fit for purpose for our existing app design as it requires major changes and solution redesign. however the end result would have worked for us.

Comment: What is the url to sub dir customers? If this is the case, you just need to use url rewrite to redirect the requested url.

Comment: We managed to do this with using yarp reverse proxy Thank you for yor help everyone.